# Can't put ground on the correct place (circuitikz)

Tags: circuitikz

I want to add some decoupling capacitors to my circuit but it's always placed wrong. It should just be at the bottom of the capacitor. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
    (opamp.out) -- ++(1,0) coordinate (out)
    (opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,4) coordinate (leftC)
    to[C]           (leftC -| out)
    to[short,-*]    (out)
    to[short,-o] ++ (1,0) node[right] {Control input}
    (leftC)   to[short,*-] ++ (0,1)  coordinate (leftR) 
    to[R]           (leftR -| out)
    to[short,-*]    (leftC -| out)
    (opamp.+) -- ++ (0,-0.5) node[ground] {}
    (opamp.-) to[short,-*] ++ (-0.4,0) coordinate (Rnode)
    (Rnode) to [R,-o] ++(-2,0)
    (Rnode) to [short] ++(0,1) coordinate (sensR) 
    (sensR) to [R,-o] ++(-2,0)
    (opamp.up)  to [short,-o]  ++ (0,2)    node [above] {${+10V}$}
    (opamp.down)to [short,-o]  ++ (0,-2)   node [below] {${-10V}$}
    (opamp.up) ++(0,1.5) coordinate (up)
    (up) to[short, *-] ++(1,0) coordinate (leftCplus)
    to[C] ++(0,-1) (leftCplus |- opamp.out) node (Cplusbottom)
    to node[ground] {}
    ;
 \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
    (opamp.out) -- ++(1,0) coordinate (out)
    (opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,4) coordinate (leftC)
    to[C]           (leftC -| out)
    to[short,-*]    (out)
    to[short,-o] ++ (1,0) node[right] {Control input}
    (leftC)   to[short,*-] ++ (0,1)  coordinate (leftR) 
    to[R]           (leftR -| out)
    to[short,-*]    (leftC -| out)
    (opamp.+) -- ++ (0,-0.5) node[ground] {}
    (opamp.-) to[short,-*] ++ (-0.4,0) coordinate (Rnode)
    (Rnode) to [R,-o] ++(-2,0)
    (Rnode) to [short] ++(0,1) coordinate (sensR) 
    (sensR) to [R,-o] ++(-2,0)
    (opamp.up)  to [short,-o]  ++ (0,2)    node [above] {${+10V}$}
    (opamp.down)to [short,-o]  ++ (0,-2)   node [below] {${-10V}$}
    (opamp.up) ++(0,1.5) coordinate (up)
    (up) to[short, *-] ++(1,0) coordinate (leftCplus)
    to[C] ++(0,-1) node (Cplusbottom) {} to ++(0,0) node[ground] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, to have good unit, you should use `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
    (opamp.out) -- ++(1,0) coordinate (out)
    (opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,4) coordinate (leftC)
    to[C]           (leftC -| out)
    to[short,-*]    (out)
    to[short,-o] ++ (1,0) node[right] {Control input}
    (leftC)   to[short,*-] ++ (0,1)  coordinate (leftR) 
    to[R]           (leftR -| out)
    to[short,-*]    (leftC -| out)
    (opamp.+) -- ++ (0,-0.5) node[ground] {}
    (opamp.-) to[short,-*] ++ (-0.4,0) coordinate (Rnode)
    (Rnode) to [R,-o] ++(-2,0)
    (Rnode) to [short] ++(0,1) coordinate (sensR) 
    (sensR) to [R,-o] ++(-2,0)
    (opamp.up)  to [short,-o]  ++ (0,2)    node [above] {$\SI{10}{\volt}$}
    (opamp.down)to [short,-o]  ++ (0,-2)   node [below] {$\SI{-10}{\volt}$}
    (opamp.up) ++(0,1.5) coordinate (up)
    (up) to[short, *-] ++(1,0) coordinate (leftCplus)
    to[C] ++(0,-1) node (Cplusbottom) {} to ++(0,0) node[ground] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]