# circuitikz/tikz: x and y coordinates of anchors for adjusting lengths?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am a new user of Tikz/circuitikz. I am trying to create the following diagram and have been able to come up with the following code so far:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (0,0) to[sV,l=$V_S$] ++(0,3) 
    to [R,l=$R_{in}$] ++(3,0) node[anchor=base,npn](npn){};

    % \draw (npn.emitter) to[short, -*] ??

    % \draw (npn.collector) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(3,0);
    % to[R, l=$R_{out}$, v=$V_{out}$] ??
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I think the issue I am facing is summarised in the picture above - I need to be able to go from the "emitter" anchor of the `npn` (labelled **E**) to the **ground** node below it, but I do not know the relative or the absolute coordinates of the ground node as indicated by the lines commented out. Knowing the y coordinate of the "emitter" anchor would also suffice. I would like to go the ground node, "stop" there, save it as a `node[ground](GND)` and then proceed with the rest of the circuit with by referencing this `GND`.

Any ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: The point which is at the same horizontal than `(0,0)` and on the vertical of the emitter is `(0,0 -| npn.E)`. Look at "perpendicular coordinate system" in Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Will try to answer tomorrow (bed time!) but surely somebody will do it before I can.

Comment: @FirstUser this should help as reference -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484628/cant-put-ground-on-the-correct-place-circuitikz

Comment: Does transistor terminals should be labeled (by C, B, E) and ended by dots (`*`)?

Answer (score 2):

As say @ Rmano in his comment, you can solve your problem by use orthogonal coordinates between `(0,0)` and emitter terminal (npb.emitter). Also the code is a wee bit shorter, if you draw ground below orthogonal coordinate:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0)   to[sV=$V_S$]  ++(0,3)
                to [R=$R_{\mathrm{in}}$] ++(3,0)    node[anchor=B,npn,] (npn) {}
        (0,0)   to[short,-*] (0,0 -| npn.E)   node[ground] {}   
                to[short] (npn.E);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or you may liked to have labeled dots of transistor terminals:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}   
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0)   to[sV=$V_S$]    ++(0,3)
                to [R=$R_{\mathrm{in}}$,-*] 
                                ++(3,0)     node[above] {B}
                                            node[anchor=B,npn,] (npn) {}
        (0,0)   to[short,-*]    (0,0 -| npn.E)   node[ground] {}
                to[short,-*]    (npn.E)     node[right] {E}
        (npn.C) node[right] {C}
                to[short,*-]    (npn.C);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
        \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
            (0,0)   
            to[sV,l=$V_S$]          ++(0,3) 
            to [R,l=$R_{in}$]       ++(3,0) node[anchor=base,npn,](npn){}
            (npn.emitter) 
            to[short, -*]           ++(0,-0.5)
            to[short,-*]            ++(0,-2)coordinate(aux) node[ground]{}
            (aux)-|(0,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```